# What type of attribute of core data choose for CGPathRef?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, attributes

I tried transformable type and save my path like this:

```
myEntityObj.mypah=(__bridge id)(anyPath);
```

t
But when I call `CGPathRef path=[allEntities objectAtIndex:n] mypath]`,this path is incorrect (dont answer on CGPath class methods etc).
What can I do?

Comment: You can't transform a CGPathRef automatically.  You need to provide your own value transformer for it.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CGPath` is a little tough to use here, because

- You can't save it directly into Core Data, since it's not a type that Core Data recognizes.
- It doesn't provide any API for converting it to a type that Core Data recognizes (e.g `NSData`).

One way or another you're going to need to convert the `CGPathRef` (or its components) to  a type that Core Data recognizes-- like `NSData`. It's most convenient to do this in a custom value transformer (look up `NSValueTransformer`). But the key is figuring out how to convert the data.

You have a couple of possibilities:

1. Don't save the path, save the data that you used to create the path. `NSValue` provides an API to convert instances to/from `CGPoint`, for example. And `NSValue` conforms to `NSCoding`. This would allow you to convert individual points to `NSData`, and Core Data can save that. When reading data, reverse the process to rebuild the `CGPathRef`.
2. Use `UIBezierPath` as a convenience container for your `CGPathRef`. You can initialize a `UIBezierPath` with a `CGPathRef`, and get a `CGPathRef` back from a `UIBezierPath`. `UIBezierPath` conforms to `NSCoding`, so as above it can be converted to `NSData` to save in Core Data.